# "Synchronized" doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have to develop a programme and a class for them which has to receive requests from atoms by a method named combinar(id) (id let us distinct between oxygen and hydrogen).

The molecule, which has to be created through the previous mentioned petitions, can only be generated when at last exist 2 complem. atoms and there are not one (O case) or two (H case) atoms waiting (in this case, new ought to wait also).

**My problem is that the message "Molécula formada" is created also, independent of the values**

```
public class Aire {

    int atomosHidrogeno = 0;
    int atomosOxigeno = 0;
    int atomosH_esperando;
    int atomosO_esperando;

    public Aire(int atH, int atO2) {
        this.atomosHidrogeno = atH;
        this.atomosOxigeno = atO2;
        this.atomosH_esperando = 0;
        this.atomosO_esperando = 0;
    }

    public void combinar(int id) {
        if (id == 0) // Hidrogeno
        {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (this.atomosH_esperando == 2 || (this.atomosHidrogeno < 1 && this.atomosOxigeno < 0)) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        this.atomosH_esperando++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    }
                }
                notifyAll();
            }
            this.atomosH_esperando--;
            System.out.println("Molécula formada");
        } else if (id == 1) // Oxigeno
        {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (this.atomosO_esperando == 1 || (this.atomosHidrogeno < 2)) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        this.atomosO_esperando++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    }
                }
                notifyAll();
            }
            this.atomosO_esperando--;
            System.out.println("Molécula formada");
        }
    }
}
```

That's my use of the class:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aire aire = new Aire(0, 0);

        Atomo[] atomos_ = new Atomo[3];
        Atomo[] atomos__ = new Atomo[3];
        Atomo[] atomos___ = new Atomo[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            atomos_[i] = new Atomo(aire,0);
            atomos_[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            atomos__[i] = new Atomo(aire,1);
            atomos__[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            atomos___[i] = new Atomo(aire,0);
            atomos___[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Atomo extends Thread {
    private int id = 0;
    Aire aire;

    public Atomo(Aire aire, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.aire = aire;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.aire.combinar(this.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe how you expect your code to behave and what exactly "*doesn't work*".

Comment: True, the message is "Molécula formada", but I is not also printed, @fabian

Comment: Note that you are decrementing the `*_esperando` variables outside the synchronized block, which is not thread-safe. You might want to move those inside the synchronized blocks.

Comment: I've written this inside them but the problem continues, @AndyTurner

Comment: How is your `Atomo` class defined?

Comment: @AndyTurner: The class is defined by the following code: `
public class Atomo extends Thread {

 private int id = 0;
 Aire aire;
 
 public Atomo(Aire aire, int id)  {
   this.id = id;
   this.aire = aire;
 }
 
 public void run()
 {
  this.aire.combinar(this.id);
 }
}
´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the increment outside the synchronized block is unsafe, as [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) points out in a comment. But more than that, the waiting behavior doesn't make sense:

```
        synchronized (this) {
            while (this.atomosH_esperando == 2 || (this.atomosHidrogeno < 1 && this.atomosOxigeno < 0)) {
                try {
                    wait();
                    this.atomosH_esperando++;
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
        this.atomosH_esperando--;
```

Why you would increment atomosH_esperando immediately after the call to wait is unclear. The point of calling wait in a loop is that the condition may be true before you enter the loop, or you may exit the wait and find the condition is still false, so there shouldn't be any incrementing of a counter here or any other logic that depends on how many times wait is called. The other thread that this is waiting on should be doing any incrementing that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but although I can count a new atom, sometimes, some molecules of H2O are created without any O atom. :-? Problems of sync.